# Вывод в консоль информации

Tags: java

Всем привет.
СОздал классы, затем объекты, добавил инфу, затем массив, как мне теперь вывести информацию о кроватях в консоль?

```
package com.company;


import java.util.Scanner;
/*
комментарий
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChildrensBeds ChildrensBeds = new ChildrensBeds();
        ChildrensBeds.name = "BTS";
        ChildrensBeds.price = 18.899f;
        ChildrensBeds.color = "White";
        ChildrensBeds.bodyMaterial = "ЛДПС";



        SingleBeds singleBeds = new SingleBeds();
        singleBeds.name = "Hoff";
        singleBeds.price = 21.435f;
        singleBeds.color = "Black";
        singleBeds.boxForLinen = true;

        DoubleBed doubleBed = new DoubleBed ();
        doubleBed.name = "ESTA";
        doubleBed.price = 39.000f;
        doubleBed.color = "Blue";
        doubleBed.countryOfOrigin = "Хорватия";

        Bed [] beds = new Bed [] {ChildrensBeds, singleBeds, doubleBed };

        for (Bed t: beds){
            System.out.println(t + " " + t + " " + t + " ");
        }
        // write your code here
    }
}

class  Bed
{
    String name;
    Float price;
    String color;
}
class ChildrensBeds extends Bed
{
    String bodyMaterial;

}

class SingleBeds extends Bed
{
    boolean boxForLinen;
}

class DoubleBed extends Bed
{
    String countryOfOrigin;
}
```

В данный момент выводит следующее:
com.company.ChildrensBeds@60addb54 com.company.ChildrensBeds@60addb54 com.company.ChildrensBeds@60addb54
com.company.SingleBeds@3f2a3a5 com.company.SingleBeds@3f2a3a5 com.company.SingleBeds@3f2a3a5
com.company.DoubleBed@4cb2c100 com.company.DoubleBed@4cb2c100 com.company.DoubleBed@4cb2c100

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо переопределить метод toString() для вашего класса, если вы работаете в intellij idea, то можете нажать alt+insert -> toString()

Comment: ChildrensBeds{bodyMaterial='ЛДПС'} ChildrensBeds{bodyMaterial='ЛДПС'} ChildrensBeds{bodyMaterial='ЛДПС'} ChildrensBeds{bodyMaterial='ЛДПС'}
SingleBeds{boxForLinen=true} SingleBeds{boxForLinen=true} SingleBeds{boxForLinen=true} SingleBeds{boxForLinen=true}
DoubleBed{countryOfOrigin='Хорватия'} DoubleBed{countryOfOrigin='Хорватия'} DoubleBed{countryOfOrigin='Хорватия'} DoubleBed{countryOfOrigin='Хорватия'}

Comment: intellij idea, а что именно нужно выделить чтобы переопределить метод ToString(), я выделяю переменные которые создал в классе и нажимаю alt+insert верно? Мне нужно вывести у каждой кровати 3 основных свойства из класса Bed, и 1 свойство индивидуальное у каждой кровати, сейчас выводит только 1 свойство у каждой кровати

Comment: https://prnt.sc/zmkrou и https://prnt.sc/zmksmp таким образом вам необходимо сделать для каждого класса, вообще советую погуглить информацию о методе toString() и классе Object, тема не очень сложная, но достаточно важная, информации в интернете достаточно больше количество

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если не хотите переопределять `toString()`, что неправильно, то можно лениво всё вывести.
Вместо:

```java
System.out.println(t + " " + t + " " + t + " ")
```

Написать:

```java
System.out.printf("Name: %s price:%f color: %s country: %s\n",
t.name, t.price, t.color, t.countryOfOrigin);
```

**UPD** Но лучше переопределить в классах метод `toString`, т.к поля у вас разные. В родителе сделать так:

```java
return String.format("Name: %s price:%f color: %s", t.name, t.price, t.color);
```

В наследниках (на примере ChildrensBeds):

```java
return super.toString() + "bodyMaterial: " + bodyMaterial;
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать гетары:

```
class  Bed
{
    String name;
    Float price;
    String color;
}
class ChildrensBeds extends Bed
{
    String bodyMaterial; 

    public Strind getData() { 
       return name+" " +prise+" "+color+" " +dodyMaterial;
    } 
}

class SingleBeds extends Bed
{
    boolean boxForLinen; 

     public Strind getData() { 
             return name+" " +prise+" "+color+" " +boxForLinen;
    } 
}

class DoubleBed extends Bed
{
    String countryOfOrigin; 
    public Strind getData() { 
         return name+" " +prise+" "+color+" " +countryOfOrigin;
    } 

}
```